# C++ Class Variable not updating

Tags: c++, trigonometry, calculation

I'm trying to code a counter for a class I made in c++.
I'm passing an amount of time, deltaT, to a method of the Wake class, which does simply adds it onto the value already stored by a variable in the class. The code is:

```
void checkPlayerWakes(int deltaT){
    for(size_t i = 0; i < game.getPlayer().getWakes().size(); i++){
        Wake& w = game.getPlayer().getWakes().at(i);
        w.age(deltaT);
    }
}
```

However, the timer which is meant to be increasing, is remaining at 0.
The code to change the timer is:

```
void Wake::age(int millis) {
    cout << "Updating : " <<  currentLife;

    this->currentLife += millis;

    setAlpha(((double)currentLife)/((double)lifeTime));

    cout << " " << currentLife << endl;
}

E.g.
first current life: 0
second current life: 16
```

I know that if I were to use

```
Wake w = something
w.age(deltaT)
```

it wouldn't work because "w" would just be a copy of the object. However, that's clearly NOT my problem here? Also game.getPlayer() also returns a reference, a PLAYERSHIP&.

Last time I had a similar problem, it was solved by calling and returning references instead of just the ClassName. Am I still doing something wrong?

Comment: You mentioned `getPlayer()`, what about `getWakes()`? :)

Comment: Oh man I must be tired .. . I can't believe I missed that :D
Thanks :O

Comment: To miss the obvious is a common thing. Two solutions - coffee or a rubber duck :) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging

Comment: Hi. I have rolled back your last edit that added the answer to the question. Here on SO we have a clear separation between questions and answers. You should up-vote any question you deem of quality or valuable to you. You should accept a question that resolved your problem (if any).

Comment: Also, casting only one operand to double is sufficient enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getWakes()` needs also to return a reference, and should return `vector&` as opposed to vector.
I'm adding this here to make sure that this question is marked as answered.